# laravel breeze app.css, app.js missing when inspected

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-breeze

I'm new to Laravel Breeze and tailwind.

After successfully installed Laravel Breeze and looking at /login page source, I couldn't match the source code and actual page source and would like to know what's going on.

In app.blade.php or guest.blade.app there are the following lines.

```
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

But when viewing login page source, it has

```
    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        /*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background-color:transparent} ...
     </style>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Nunito';
        }
    </style>
```

And no javascript is loaded.

I'm expecting to see just the link to `public/css/app.css` and `public/js/app.js` but no such thing here.

So if anyone can explain how Laravel Breeze works regarding to including css and js
and how I can extend tailwind css to other pages and use js in other pages, I'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the assets installed with Breeze. To do so, just run the following commands on your project directory:

```
npm install 
npm run dev
```

If you check the Public folder on your Laravel app, you should see the CSS and JS compiled. Refresh the page, and the style should look OK.

Documentation reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation